# How to make ROM pack tool in Android?

Tags: android

Pack ROM
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/lollipop-wear-release/ext4_utils/

I just make it by the following command. (reference from Google searched)

```
gcc -o make_ext4fs -Icore/libsparse/include -lz extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs_main.c extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs.c extras/ext4_utils/ext4fixup.c extras/ext4_utils/ext4_utils.c extras/ext4_utils/allocate.c extras/ext4_utils/contents.c extras/ext4_utils/extent.c extras/ext4_utils/indirect.c extras/ext4_utils/uuid.c extras/ext4_utils/sha1.c extras/ext4_utils/wipe.c core/libsparse/backed_block.c core/libsparse/output_file.c core/libsparse/sparse.c core/libsparse/sparse_crc32.c core/libsparse/sparse_err.c core/libsparse/sparse_read.c
```

But encountered the following error.

> extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs_main.c:33:29: fatal error:
>   selinux/selinux.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
>   extras/ext4_utils/make_ext4fs.c:63:29: fatal error: selinux/selinux.h:
>   No such file or directory